# Taken from ISS 3-30-2017 7:45AM Eastern

Tags: features

I found these peninsula very interesting.  Tracker showed ISS over the bottom portion of South America and the features resemble portions of the Falkland Islands but I'd love to explore more.  Any ideas?   [image]

Answer (score 1):

thats in greece near Thessaloniki:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Thessaloniki,+Greece/@40.3355457,23.2027998,203753m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x9662c5410425af2f:0x505e1131102b91d!2sChile!3b1!8m2!3d-35.675147!4d-71.542969!3m4!1s0x14a838f41428e0ed:0x9bae715b8d574a9!8m2!3d40.6410515!4d22.9449463

Found it by doing a reverse google image search. It was posted by a greek twitter account.

Comment: Whoa, that is amazing!  Begs the question as to how current the "Live" streaming from ISS really is.  Thanks!